# What happens to questions after Triage?

Tags: support, review, triage

When a question is in the Triage review queue, what action will be taken if the Triage result is **Should Be Improved** or the result is **Unsalvageable**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦, how does this actually work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252048/question-flags-queues-edits-roomba-community-how-does-this-actually-work)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: I rather strongly dislike "go read this long detailed reference, it is totally exactly and entirely your question explained in five days or less or your money back" dupe-flags. The linked dupe just barely mentions Triage at all in passing in a much longer discussion.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The answer's flowchart and section about Triage pretty much explain it exactly, and that answer is much more recent and answered by a CM.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Like I said, "Read The Flowchart Manual" is not an appropriate use for dupe-flags, generally speaking.

Comment: @NathanTuggy While I'd agree on main Q&A sites, on meta sites [it's acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work) to close questions as duplicates of broader ones, if there's an answer available at the duplicate, even if the questions are merely related. I'd also agree if the answer here was more recent, but I stand by my flag because the answer there reflects the current behavior and was posted by an SE employee.

Comment: Also, in case you didn't notice, the same is in text form in a section below the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, no action is taken when a question does not "Look OK". This feature is currently in testing.

Quoting from [Shog9♦'s post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage):

> However, **first we need to make sure that works!** In particular,
>   before we start filtering questions from the home page or
>   building a queue for helpful editors, we need to make sure the two
>   pieces we've built already actually do what they're intended to.
>
> So right now, there's no visibility restrictions or helper queue.
>   After a few days, I'll come back with the results:
>
> - If it looks like things are working, we'll start dropping questions that don't "Look OK" from the home page.
> - If it's *not* working, we'll fix them. Change the guidance, the number of reviews required to complete a task, etc.
>
> Once we're all happy with both the behavior of Triage and the
>   appearance of the home page, we'll roll out a Helper/Editor workflow.
>
> Go, review, & let us know how it works!

**When this feature comes out of testing** and is rolled out, then a question may go through the following paths:

- All "Looks OK" questions will be posted on the homepage, where they can be answered
- Other questions can go to either the close / moderator flag queue where they can be reviewed and eventually deleted or appear in a new "Help and Improvement" queue where they can be edited