# Is there a "time limit" on First Posts?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

I was just curious if the term "First Post" is as straight forward as the title implies...

Let says I joined a site, looked around, voted on stuff, but never asked or answered a question. Does it matter if I finally do make a post a great time later (over a year)? Will this post come up in the "First Post" reviews?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be put into the review queue. It is still the first post even if you post after a year.

The answers the users post till the "new user restrictions" are removed, will be put into "Late answers" queue if the questions are old.

Bluefeet gave an awesome analysis on how reviews, flags, community♦ work in their answer. It is easily understand able through the flow chart in that answer.

[Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦, how does this actually work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/357396)

From that answer,

> When a question is first posted it can initially take a few paths:
>
> - If it's a first question by a user, then it will automatically head into the [First Posts Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts).

For example, Shog9 is `user:2` on Hinduism Stack Exchange and the oldest user on the site in terms of registration (only after Adam Lear though). When he tried to post an answer, he was shown a disclaimer* there which is usually shown for [users who post for the first time](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/877/5212).

[image: Image for first posters on Hinduism Stack Exchange]

You may also visit [New Review Queue: First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146988/357396) to now more about First post review queues.

*<sub>Site specific feature</sub>

Comment: How do you know what message was shown to Shog9? Because you're his sock puppet? (I'm just joking, [I know you're not](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6511937#6511937), but I'm still curious to know how you know what message was shown to him).

Comment: @DonaldDuck Shog9 and I share screens :P he screen shot is taken from one of his answers. I linked in the answer, See this again. https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/877/5212

Answer (score 2):

There is no time limit on first posts. There's even an edge case where an old post from a long-established user may how up in the first posts review queue long after it was posted. If a user's first post gets deleted, the system detects that the user's oldest non-deleted post hasn't gone through first posts review and will put it in the queue.